# Show larger images in control panel entries

Tags: control-panel, config

Is there a way to show the images in the control panel entries (both in the detail of the entry and in the overview list using the new customisable columns in 2.5).  The standard preview of the images is so small it hardly is visible to control panel users.

Edit:
On the feedback site this feature request seems to have made it in one way or another to the 2.5 build.  Does anyone know how to use it?

http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7192735-better-image-preview-and-edit-window-for-asset-fie

Answer (score 2):

The [Asset Preview](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/assetpreview) plugin is what you need. This allows you to toggle previews of assets by clicking on them and tapping the space bar. You can also use the arrow keys to navigate through all of the assets on a page.

Comment: Thanks, but is not really fit for purpose here. It doesn't have a solution for the overview pages of entries (that since 2.5 can show images) and there is an additional step (the click + spacebar) in viewing large scale images in the detailpages.

Comment: Edited the original question as according to http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7192735-better-image-preview-and-edit-window-for-asset-fie this functionality made it to 2.5, but I can't find info on how to use it.